# cannot install SVN connectors in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I am running Eclipe Juno and trying to get SVN installed, ive included all the svn jars avaliable from the http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php.
when at the select connectors to install screen when i try and install i get the error.

`Problms occured while performing installation: HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (-1):http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/juno-site/context.xml`

Solved:
The issue is an internet blocking exception rule i cannot change so instead i am now using subclipse not subversion.

Comment: Don't mark [SOLVED] in the title - you can accept your own answer after a certain time passes, and that's the indicator that it is solved.

Comment: okay thanks for that i didn't know. now i do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is not to use Subversive and to use [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) Instead. Works fine.

So i would suggest anyone else who faces this issue to check your firewall rules/Outgoing exception rules. For me i can not change these as i have no control over th firewall.

Answer (score 1):

The update which you mentioned 
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.1/update-site
works fine for me. Thanks and i am able to install the plugin.

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/   this doesn't work actually.